# How to create a simple two lined border with swing?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border

I want to surround a JPanel with a light border and then a darker one around it. Each should be very thin. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this. When I looked at the Borders in swing, none seemed to fit my needs. Beveled Boarder sort of worked, except for the shadows. Is there any way to do this?

All I want is to be able to specify the thickness and color of each border and have one outside the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,2),BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,3))`

This will create two (black) line border with differnt thickness

Comment: Is there any way to make them thinner than 1? That's still shows up too thick for what I want (and is still bigger than a pixel, so it can get smaller)

Comment: @MikeG Try using without int attribute and check if the defaultborder suits your needs.

Comment: That's much better, but even thinner would be great (I'm trying to make it very subtle).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a CompoundBorder to do this, and then use two LineBorders in your CompoundBorder.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a compond border you can draw a two-line border like below:

```
CompoundBorder compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY),
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
containerPanel.setBorder(compound);
```